# Cocoa error 256 core data

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have error "Cocoa error 256" when I try to save data. How to fix it? And what problem?

Answer (score 6):

According to the help reference in Xcode:

> NSFileReadUnknownError
>   Read error, reason unknown
>
> Available in Mac OS X v10.4 and later.
>
> Declared in FoundationErrors.h.

Sadly, that's probably not too helpful, though it is an unknown -read- error.

Comment: Is it possible that the location of the sqlite file has changed or the file has been damamged somehow? </speculation>

Answer (score 2):

If its a core data error there is probably an actual error object somewhere near where the error occurs. If you dump the error objects userInfo dictionary, you can usually get a lot more detail than just the error code itself.

Answer (score 2):

This is what it boils down to (as Tegeril said)

> NSFileReadUnknownError Read error,
>   reason unknown
>
> Available in Mac OS X v10.4 and later.
>
> Declared in FoundationErrors.h.

A file can also be a resource located at a URL/URI, if the URL has unencoded characters it can cause this type of error.

Check the path to the resource/file.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into exactly this error when populating an SQLite database for an iOS app using a custom script (ie not using Core Data).  It turns out that there is some metadata which you have to update yourself, after adding new rows. Find the row in Z_PRIMARYKEY where Z_NAME equals the name of the table you've just inserted into.  Make sure that Z_MAX in this row is equal to the highest value of Z_PK in the table you've inserted the rows into.  In my case, as soon as I updated Z_MAX with the correct number, the error went away.

So, for the "ZAUTHOR" table:

```
SELECT z_pk FROM ZAUTHOR ORDER BY z_pk DESC LIMIT 1; /* Returns 1234 */
UPDATE Z_PRIMARYKEY SET z_max = 1234 WHERE z_name = 'Author';
```

[This is the article which helped me track down the error.](http://blog.beefyapps.com/2010/03/coredata-sqlite3-database-constraint-failed-error/)

Answer (score 0):

I get this error on Xcode 6 (& 7) when switching a network connection while the Simulator is open. For example moving from one wireless network to another. The solution for me is to Quit Simulator and restart.