# NSURL into NSData (Cocoa error 256.)

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I need to serialize my NSURL.

object is type of NSManagedObject.

```
NSURL *objectURIRepresentation = [[object objectID] URIRepresentation];
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *objectIDData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:objectURIRepresentation options:NSDataReadingMapped error:&error];
```

I get error: (Cocoa error 256.).
Any ideas? Something tells me, using `dataWithContentsOfURL:` is not good idea.

**Update**

One more question which is put as a comment mistakenly:

What is the difference between `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:uri];` and `[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:uri];`?

Thanks.

Comment: NSManagedObject != NSData. and http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/08/safely-fetching-nsmanagedobject-by-uri.html

Comment: What is the difference between `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:uri];` and `[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:uri];`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, your code does not attempt to serialize a NSURL object, it attempts to create a data object out of the data at the URL returned as the URI of a managed object.

Secondly, that is never going to work.

`[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` will try to read a file at a particular URL. The URI of a managed object represents an object stored in pieces with many others inside a persistent file like a SQLite database.

The URI only allows a managed object context to identify a particular object in its own store. The URI is gibberish to anything else other than the context.

NSManagedObject does not implement the NSCoder protocol so managed objects cannot be serialized. I'm not sure what you want to do here but you can't do it this way.

Comment: "`[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` will try to read a file at a particular URL." - Thanks for this sentence. I absolutely get it now. I just cant store NSManagedObject so I store its ID.

Comment: Be aware of one major gotcha when using managed object IDs. The true fixed ID is only generated when the object is persisted to the store i.e. after a context save. Prior to that the object ID is just temporary and will change after a save. So, always save an object before capturing its ID for use outside the context.

Comment: @TechZen then how to get NSData of this?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned here [Cocoa error 256 core data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915478/cocoa-error-256-core-data/1915525#1915525)
error code 256 can occur when an unknown error is occurred in reading the resource or the path has some encoded characters in it.

What it seems to me is you are trying to get the data from `NSManagedObject`. Hence as @fluchtpunkt suggested you should look for http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/08/safely-fetching-nsmanagedobject-by-uri.html

Now coming to your second question `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:uri];` returns data for a web url or a local resource in your documents directory. While `[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:uri];` returns the `NSData` object containing the **encoded form of the object graph** whose root object is given.

Comment: Thanks. At the end, the second question/answer was the right one.

Answer (score 2):

try to add "Http://" before in the link

Comment: This helped me. Such a silly mistake to make can't believe it!