# Error 256 Reading via NSString's initWithContentsOfFile

Tags: objective-c, xcode, file-io

I am attempting to read a number of files from a directory tree inside the Documents directory within my App andbox.
Most of them are xml files which I read with :

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:packagefile. 
RXMLElement *rxml = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLData:data];
```

All but ***one*** them read OK. But ***one*** does not read and I get  error code 256.
For the bad file I can also try :

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:packagefile options:0 error:&err];
```

but the same error code comes back . (Hence I think my issue is not related to the actual xml content of the file).

Clearing out the sandbox and copying all the files back in programatically in my App makes no difference.

What can be wrong here? What else can I do?

Comment: How is error code 256 returned?  I can only see an `NSError` being returned.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103788/nsurl-into-nsdata-cocoa-error-256

Comment: The error code is inside the NsError

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this problem ('inexplicable error code 256'.)     Hopefully  this solution will be helpful to other developers who hit this issue.

**It had run out of file handles.**

In my App I had a also logging function  which logged activity to file (a bit like Log4J). This took each logged statement – opened a file using a 'NSFileHandle' followed by 'seekToEndOfFile' followed by 'writeData'.

I was relying mistakenly upon the ARC disposing and closing the file on exit from the logging procedure. Clearly ARC does **not** close the file and eventually the system runs out of file handles.

The solution is simply to call 'closeFile' as one would in Java or C.