# issue with getting data from url

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here is the code I wrote

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=CAADbwxRRgq8BANULcGGn3d4NPZB4LlP3tCL9YjYH3Nd0fD2XvgjG0qTECEmOsFhNhcu4NCdgYzQK3lYaATiedLRP4ZAIRgf8FBtDBYd22z5BrMabHlex12nZAbm8UfJTrPVRw5rjN8abi9"];


NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSError* error = nil;
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
if (error) {
     NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
     NSLog(@"Data has loaded successfully.");
}
```

I got the error

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x218446a0

```
{NSURL=https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=CAADbwxRRgq8BANULcGGn3d4NPZB4LlP3tCL9YjYH3Nd0fD2XvgjG0qTECEmOsFhNhcu4NCdgYzQK3lYaATiedLRP4ZAIRgf8FBtDBYd22z5BrMabHlex12nZAbm8UfJTrPVRw5rjN8abi9ZBoVD1DYVZCo8hcZC0n2CnMyk3ryeCQntRpdZCc2e}
```

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106087/nscocoaerrordomain-code-256)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice explanation of why NSCocoaErrorDomain occurs.

[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: not returning data for URL that shows in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020494/nsdata-datawithcontentsofurl-not-returning-data-for-url-that-shows-in-browser)

Read it and see if any of the suggestions in that answer might be useful to you.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=CAADbwxRRgq8BANULcGGn3d4NPZB4LlP3tCL9YjYH3Nd0fD2XvgjG0qTECEmOsFhNhcu4NCdgYzQK3lYaATiedLRP4ZAIRgf8FBtDBYd22z5BrMabHlex12nZAbm8UfJTrPVRw5rjN8abi9"];


NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSError* error = nil;
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30] returningResponse:nil error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Data has loaded successfully.");
}
```

Albeit, I have no idea why your other request fails. Error code 256 isn't very descriptive.